# Populating html divs with respective json data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

How to populate number of nested html divs from external file(div tag, css class and json object names are same) using jquery/javascript(loops and switch case).
I am giving a vague idea of html and json structures.

```
    div1
     div1.1
      div1.1.1
      div1.1.2
      div1.1.3

  json array
   [
    1
    {
      1.1
      {[
        1.1.1
        1.1.2
        1.1.3
        ]
       }
       }
     ]
```

Comment: Have you considered using jquery? The docs are pretty thorough.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to generate a jquery code for this..

Comment: So how do you need to load the values into the elements? After page load?

Comment: What do you mean by `div1` etc? Do you mean like this? `<div id="div1"></div>`?

Comment: by div 1 as in div with class name 1

Comment: <div class="1"></div>

Comment: so what i am asking is that the data in object 1.1.3 should go in its respective div which is div1.1.3

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var str = "";
//object that contain your JSON
var jsonObj;
//first iteration
$.each(jsonObj,function(i,data){
//here you will create div1
str = str + '<div1>';
    $.each(data.jsonObj1.1,function(j,data){
        str = str + '<div1.1>';
        $.each(data.jsonObj1.1,function(k,data){
        str = str + '<div1.'+k+1+'>';
        });
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: if you want running  code please post your proper json and html what you wnat i will send you the running code on JSfield

Comment: @Adi- here is the whole link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609010/how-to-populate-number-of-nested-html-divs-from-external-json-file?noredirect=1#comment56963927_34609010

Comment: @Adi- Could you provide me with the running js code?

Comment: @adi- could you help at this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737757/creating-nested-divs-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment57221796_34737757