# How to populate number of nested html divs from external json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

How to fetch data from json objects/arays(in external json file) to their respective nested divs in html on the onLoad of html page.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>first2</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsoncss.css">
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="MyAccountsLabel">
                <div class="MyAccountsLeft">My Accounts</div>
            </div>
            <div class="LeftSection">
                <div class="LeftSectionTopLeft">I Have (in 4 Accounts)</div>
                <div class="LeftSectionTopRight">+USD 13,700.00</div>
                <div class="MyMainSavings">
                    <div class="MyMainSavingsTop">
                        <table class="MyMainSavingsTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class="InterestRate">

                        </div>
                        <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="MyMainSavingsBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>

                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyEverydayExpenses">
                    <div class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
                        <table class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class=".InterestRate">
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="MyEverydayExpensesBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyDeposit">
                    <div class="MyDepositTop">
                        <table class="MyDepositTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                        <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="MyDepositBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="FavDeposit">
                    <div class="FavDepositTop">
                        <table class="FavDepositTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                        <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="FavDepositBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="RightSection">
                <div class="RightSectionTopLeft">I Owe (from 3 Accounts)</div>
                <div class="RightSectionTopRight">-USD 33,4500.00</div>
                <div class="HomeLoan">
                    <div class="HomeLoanTop">
                        <table class="HomeLoanTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                        <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="HomeLoanBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Ruby">
                    <div class="RubyTop">
                        <table class="RubyTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class=".InterestRate">

                        </div>
                        <div class="regular">Regular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="RubyBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="MyOverdraft">
                    <div class="MyOverdraftTop">
                        <table class="MyOverdraftTop">
                            <tr>
                                <td>MyOverdraft</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </table>
                        <div class=".InterestRate">

                        </div>
                        <div class="regular"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="MyOverdraftBottom">
                        <table class="tablebottom">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="right"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="right"></td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSON file:

```
var mainObject = {
    "Main": [{
        "I_Have": [{
            "MyMainSavings": {
                "MyMainSavingsTop": {
                    "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                    "AccountNumber": "x726",
                    "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
                    "Rate": ""
                },
                "MyMainSavingsBottom": [{
                    "Available": "Available",
                    "Value": "$4329"
                }, {
                    "Clear": "Clear",
                    "Value": "$3456"
                }, {
                    "Hold": "Hold",
                    "Value": "$5000"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "MyEverydayExpenses": {
                "MyEverydayExpensesTop": {
                    "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                    "AccountNumber": "x726",
                    "Balance": "USD 600.00",
                    "Rate": ""
                },
                "MyEverydayExpensesBottom": [{
                    "Available": "Available",
                    "Value": "$4329"
                }, {
                    "Clear": "Clear",
                    "Value": "$3456"
                }, {
                    "Hold": "Hold",
                    "Value": "$7300"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "FavDeposit": {
                "FavDepositTop": {
                    "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                    "AccountNumber": "x726",
                    "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
                    "Rate": "@4.5%"
                },
                "FavDepositBottom": [{
                    "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
                    "Value": "$4009"
                }, {
                    "Term": "Term",
                    "Value": "$1156"
                }, {
                    "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
                    "Value": "$5000"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "MyDeposit": {
                "MyDepositTop": {
                    "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
                    "AccountNumber": "x726",
                    "Balance": "USD 8,600.00",
                    "Rate": "@4.5%"
                },
                "MyDepositBottom": [{
                    "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
                    "Value": "$4329"
                }, {
                    "Term": "Term",
                    "Value": "$3456"
                }, {
                    "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
                    "Value": "$5000"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
```

so the question is that the object MyMainSavings in json should point at div with class name MyMainSavings and so on for their respective children.

Comment: The html code has data in it. Essentially the data from html file should be removed and only come from json. By data I mean textual values appearing on the page. eg <div>abc</div> - This must not be the case, abc should come from json

Comment: @Rory McCrossan what is the jquery/javascript code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Your JSON object is invalid.Can you validate it and repost it

Comment: What I mean is the MyMainSavings div is corresponding to the MyMainSavings object in json, then MyMainSavingsTop div is corresponding to MyMainSavingsTop in json, so I want to populate the data in its corresponding element div through javascript/jquery. In short elements of same name  should find themselves in the html file.

Comment: @Kamal - I checked it....It is showing valid

Answer (score 0):

To access the json simply do

```
mainObject.Main[0].I_Have[0].MyMainSavings.MyMainSavingsTop
```

If you want to list the content and get the names you can do

```
for (var i in mainObject.Main[0]) 
     console.log(i);

> I_Have

for (var i in mainObject.Main[0].I_Have[0]) 
     console.log(i);

> MyMainSavings
```

Comment: I did not understand the console.log(i) and > I_Have.

Comment: When you do a for(var i in array), var i contains the keys for arrays, therefore I_Have was a key to de array mainObject.Main[0], as MyMainSavings, is a key to mainObject.Main[0].I_Have[0].